# 'Where in' T-SQL implementation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that take many input parameters including an @userID.

Now, in the core of the SP I select from a view using the following Where close :

```
Where userID = @userID
```

This works fine. Now I want to pass multiple users to be able wo query it like this :

```
where userID in (1,2,...)
```

How can I pass the value 1,2 from one input parameter ?

Thanks

Comment: This has been asked SOOO many times on SO. You are aware that you can search other questions, and read their answers?

Comment: @astander: good point. I answered without thinking...

Comment: @astandar / @mitch a great approach here is to link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209686/passing-list-to-sql-stored-procedure or another canonical, so it shows up in the faq http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/faq ... or update the wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info to include it

Comment: why not passing the userID's in a table-variable, e.g.@TuserID. inside the sp you could do an inner join @TuserID on @TuserID.UserID = userID...

Answer (score 1):

Create a function split:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
       @List nvarchar(2000),
       @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table
(

       Id int identity(1,1),
       Value nvarchar(2000)
)
AS
BEGIN

   While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
   Begin
           Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
           Select  Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1)))
           Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
   End

   Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
           Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

           Return

--select Value from dbo.Split('item1, item2, item3',',')
END
GO
```

And call the function with @PASS and use it inside a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create an input parameter which is a table varaible and send in the array as a table that you join to instead of using in. Read about this in BOL as it can be a little tricky to set up.