# Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

Hello I am getting this error -

> 'Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint'

while running this is the code:

```
string idString = "1,2,3,4";

string updateSql = "UPDATE DistinctClubcard SET ProcessedYorN = 'Y' " + "WHERE CLUBCARD_NUMBER in (@flag) ";

SqlCommand UpdateCmd = new SqlCommand(updateSql, cn);
UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@flag", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2000));
UpdateCmd.Parameters["@flag"].Value = idString ;
UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The resulting SQL query will look similar to `UPDATE DistinctClubcard SET ProcessedYorN='Y' WHERE CLUBCARD_NUMBER in ('1,2,3,4')`, notice the quotes around the numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't work - A `SQL IN (...)` query needs an *array* of sql parameters, it will not just work with passing a single string parameter. Instead use a separate parameter for each value and an array of integer values:

```
string idString = "1,2,3,4";
var ids = idString.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();

for(int i =0;i< ids.Length;i++)
{
  UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@flag"+i, SqlDbType.BigInt));
  UpdateCmd.Parameters["@flag"+i].Value = ids[i];
}
```

Of course that also changes your query where you have to account for your parameters:

```
string flags =  string.Join(",", ids.Select((s, i) => "@flag" + i));
string updateSql = string.Format("UPDATE DistinctClubcard SET ProcessedYorN = 'Y' WHERE CLUBCARD_NUMBER in ({0})",flags);
```

Comment: +1 after the edit to change the query to match the list of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is going to passed to SQL Server as a single value, not as a replacement within the query.  There are different ways you could send multiple values, including (for SQL Server 2008) table-valued parameters, or possibly formatting the parameter as XML to be parsed on the SQL Server side.  (I used this solution once, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you can't find another solution.)

See this question on SO for more in-depth answers: [Passing List<> to SQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209686/passing-list-to-sql-stored-procedure)