# Want to send large data(ex, List<T>) to SP, using NHibernate in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, io

How can I send "List" to SP in .NET?
I used loop util now, but it has low performance beacuse of overfull I/O Connection.
So, I think that Sending "List" to DB Server is solution.

(Under code is Sample)

```
ISession session = ....;
Foreach(ProductDto PD in insertList)
{
  IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec Log @A=:a, @B=:b");
  query.SetDateTime("A", ProductDto.a);
  query.SetString("B", ProductDto.b);
  query.ExecuteUpdate();
}
```

Comment: You can pass a table into the SP Take a look at this, see if it helps:  http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/

Answer (score 0):

Calling of stored procedure and passing it a list as input is answered here: [Passing List<> to SQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209686/passing-list-to-sql-stored-procedure)